# Two methods convert strings to and from class properties

Tags: c#

I have a class that stores some data and two methods that set this data from strings and convert it back to a string.

I call `AddDetail(string detail)` when reading multiple lines of a text file, so it gets called many times.

I don't like multiple `if` and `else if` statements and I use loops whenever possible.

Is it possible to use loops in this case or somehow optimize these methods?

````cs
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Details
{
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public string? Address { get; set; }
    public string? Phone { get; set; }
    public Uri? Email { get; set; }
    public Uri? Website { get; set; }
    public TimeOnly? OpenFrom { get; set; }
    public TimeOnly? OpenTill { get; set; }

    public void AddDetail(string detail)
    {
        if (detail.StartsWith("- Date: "))
        {
            if (DateTime.TryParse(detail.Replace("- Date: ", string.Empty), out DateTime date))
            {
                Date = date;
            }
        }
        else if (detail.StartsWith("- Address: "))
        {
            Address = detail.Replace("- Address: ", string.Empty);
        }
        else if (detail.StartsWith("- Phone: "))
        {
            Phone = detail.Replace("- Phone: ", string.Empty);
        }
        else if (detail.StartsWith("- Email: "))
        {
            if (Uri.TryCreate(detail.Replace("- Email: ", string.Empty), UriKind.Absolute, out Uri? uri))
            {
                Email = uri;
            }
        }
        else if (detail.StartsWith("- Website: "))
        {
            if (Uri.TryCreate(detail.Replace("- Website: ", string.Empty), UriKind.Absolute, out Uri? uri))
            {
                Website = uri;
            }
        }
        else if (detail.StartsWith("- Open: "))
        {
            string open = detail.Replace("- Open: ", string.Empty);

            string[] fromTill = open.Split('-');

            if (fromTill.Length == 2)
            {
                if (TimeOnly.TryParse(fromTill[0].Trim(), out TimeOnly from))
                {
                    OpenFrom = from;
                }

                if (TimeOnly.TryParse(fromTill[1].Trim(), out TimeOnly till))
                {
                    OpenTill = till;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new();

        if (Date is not null)
            stringBuilder.AppendLine("- Date: " + Date);

        if (Address is not null)
            stringBuilder.AppendLine("- Address: " + Address);

        if (Phone is not null)
            stringBuilder.AppendLine("- Phone: " + Phone);

        if (Email is not null)
            stringBuilder.AppendLine("- Email: " + Email);

        if (Website is not null)
            stringBuilder.AppendLine("- Website: " + Website);

        if (OpenFrom is not null && OpenTill is not null)
            stringBuilder.AppendLine($"- Open: {OpenFrom} - {OpenTill}");

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 2):

Usually big chain of `if` condition is a code smell and polymorphism is usually the solution. I suggest using it in combination with immutability - then you don't "parse", but create the object from the string. If not, I would add builder pattern and use polymorphism (explained below) only for the builder, that will in the end create/modify your class as it exists now.

Create interface of your class, possibly with abstract class too and then implementation for each possibility, for example `DateDetails`, etc. Your `parse` method will become constructor rather than modifier, your properties all become read-only if possible. Then you need a factory, which decides based on your `detail` string, what constructor to call and what instance to create (this will be basically iterating over a loop).

I should note, that your whole design is weird, since you are in each case filling only 1-2 fields of the whole class, so it is always almost empty.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I call `AddDetail(string detail)` when reading multiple lines of a text file, so it gets called many times.

Comment: That's useful to know. Could be useful to add sample of this file for more context and to be able to make it run on sample data.